# why am I getting undefined in console.log in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties

I have sent object to properties as

```
objValue = {
    key1 = 'value1',
    key2 = ['a','b','c','d','e'],
}
<childComponent objValue = {objValue} />
```

then in my child i am trying to access property

```
class ....{
    const {obj} = this.props.objValue,
    console.log({obj.key2})
}
```

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in this line:

```
const {obj} = this.props.obj;
```

Write it like this:

```
const {objValue} = this.props;
```

Reason is you are passing the `object` in `props` with key `objValue`, so you need to use either `this.props.objValue.key` or destructure it like this:

```
const {objValue} = this.props;
```

Now you can use `objValue.key2` it will print the proper value.

`props` will be something like this:

```
{
   objValue: {
      key1 : 'value1',
      key2 : ['a','b','c','d','e'],
   }
   .....
}
```

Check the [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for more information on `Object destructuring`.

Few Changes:

**1** Name of the react component must start with uppercase letter, otherwise it will be treated as html element not react component, so use `ChildComponent` instead of `childComponent`.

**2** You used `=` inside `object` to specify the value, use `:` in place of that.

Check this example:

```js
var a = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

var {b} = a;

console.log(b);

console.log({b});
```

Comment: yeah i am using exactly as written above but it is not working

Comment: nope i am getting undefined, in parentComponent i clearly see whole object, but when trying to access its property with array it is not working, but simple property i can access. I don´t understand what am i doing wrong

Comment: at what place you are using the `console.log` ?

Comment: one more issue is there, name of the react component must start with uppercase, n u r using `childComponent` use `ChildComponent`, it should work.

Comment: const patientZero = {
  patientName: 'Harry Voskoboynikov',
  sex: 'male',
  age: '28',
  citizenship: 'Russian',
  symptompsList: ['Chest pain', 'Fever', 'Blood Pressure'],
  anamensisList: ['Diabetes', 'Allergic with Peniciline and peanuts', 'Carpal tunner issues', 'flue'],
};                                                                                                                                   class {

  render() {
    const { patientZero } = this.props;
    console.log(patientZero.anamnesisList);                                                           need List

Comment: I am using everynaming ok , i just used this snippet as example .. i can pass properties fine, except for those with array - i need whole array content in lists

Comment: one more issue in object use used `=` instead of `:` , replace that also, it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your syntaxis, you use = in object, instead :, and Mayank right, name of component should start with Capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i actually found typos in base object definition now it is working.